# Returning Twitter handles per dataframe row

Tags: r, twitter, stringr, rtweet

Given the following dataframe:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("Testing @cspenn @test @hi","this is a tweet","this is a tweet with @mention of @twitter"))
names(df)[1] <- "content"
```

I'm trying to extract the individual twitter handles per row, instead of all at once.

From [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756338/creating-edges-rows-for-several-mentions-in-one-tweet), I have this function which spits them all out, but I need them to remain contained to each row.

```
df$handles <- plyr::ddply(df, c("content"), function(x){
    mention <- unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x$content, "@\\w+"))
    # some tweets do not contain mentions, making this necessary:
    if (length(mention) > 0){
        return(data.frame(mention = mention))
    } else {
        return(data.frame(mention = NA))    
    }
})
```

How I extract the handles only per row, instead of all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(mentions = str_extract_all(content, "@\\w+"))
```

Output:

```
                                    content            mentions
1                 Testing @cspenn @test @hi @cspenn, @test, @hi
2                           this is a tweet                    
3 this is a tweet with @mention of @twitter  @mention, @twitter
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

```
xy <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$content, "@\\w+")
xy <- sapply(xy, FUN = paste, collapse = ", ")  # have all names concatenated
cbind(df, xy)

                                    content                  xy
1                 Testing @cspenn @test @hi @cspenn, @test, @hi
2                           this is a tweet                    
3 this is a tweet with @mention of @twitter  @mention, @twitter
```

Comment: Thank you - ended up using the tidyverse solution.